# Programs can't find Cross-env

Tags: node.js, npm, nodemon, cross-env

I got the source code from someone I know. But he uses Linux and I use Windows.
I used the following command to run this program.

```
"scripts": {
        "dev": "nodemon --watch src --watch package.json --watch tsconfig.js --delay 1 --exec 'cross-env HTTP_PORT=4080 NODE_ENV=develop ts-node' src/index.ts",
        "lint": "tslint -p .",
        "build": "tsc",
        "dto:build": "tsc src/dto/*.ts --declaration --emitDeclarationOnly --experimentalDecorators --outDir dto",
        "dto:publish": "rm -rf dto; npm run dto:build && cp package.dto.json dto/package.json && cd dto && npm publish --access public"
    },
```

```
npm run dev
```

When I run this script, I got the following result.

```
[nodemon] 2.0.13
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): src\**\* package.json tsconfig.js
[nodemon] watching extensions: ts,json
[nodemon] starting `'cross-env HTTP_PORT=4080 NODE_ENV=develop ts-node' src/index.ts`
''cross-env'은(는) 내부 또는 외부 명령, 실행할 수 있는 프로그램, 또는
배치 파일이 아닙니다.
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

''cross-env'은(는) 내부 또는 외부 명령, 실행할 수 있는 프로그램, 또는
배치 파일이 아닙니다.
<< this mean 'cross-env' is not recognized as an internal or external command (maybe)

As a result I don't know how to solve this.

I also installed cross-env using npm install.

I expect this to be a different command for Linux and Windows.

I would appreciate it if you could tell me the cause of this and how to fix it.
[I'll attach a rough file structure.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csj79.png)